# How to read value of a web form field from C# Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web form from external URL in WebView control in a C# Desktop application, I wan to fetch a fields value from web form to application. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the IDs of the fields, then you cann gain their values like this:

```
string fieldValue = 
      webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(YOUR_FIELD_ID).GetAttribute("value");
```

Make sure that you call these Methods not until the webview has finished loading!

Answer (score 0):

The webbrowser control exposes the content of the page.

So you can navigate the DOM and find the field you need.

[Accessing the DHTML DOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290341%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

I know the link is not resent, but the method is more or less the same.